# Dart Flutter: Why use getter instead of setter for Stream Sink?

Tags: dart, stream, sink

To my basic understanding of `Stream` and `sink` we add data to sink in order to pass it through the stream but to add it we use a getter instead of setter, which I find counter-intuitive (see example below), could you please explain in simple words why is it how it is and not the other way around?

Example:

```
class BlogPostViewModel {
  StreamController<List<BlogPost>> _blogPostListController = StreamController.broadcast();
  Stream<List<BlogPost>> get outBlogPostList => _blogPostListController.stream;
  Sink<List<BlogPost>> get _inBlogPostList => _blogPostListController.sink; // Here why use get and not a setter?
}
```

In advance, thank you.

Comment: You could. There's no real reason for not doing it.

Comment: @RémiRousselet could you explain more please?

Comment: There is no real downside to using a `set foo(int value) => _sink.add(value)` over `Sink<int> get foo => _sink`. The only difference is that you do not have access to `Sink.close`, but it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getter` and `setter` concept is a way to simulate access to a field in a class but control the behavior of this. So behind the scene there can even not be any variable if we want to e.g. have a getter which fetch some data from somewhere each time (please don't do that).

`get` and `set` are therefore methods called when we try to get and set the value of this field:

```
class MyClass {
  void get test => print('You called get');
  set test(void input) => print('You called set');
}

void main() {
  final obj = MyClass();
  obj.test;         // You called get
  obj.test = null;  // You called set
}
```

So in your case, you want to make so when you try to get the "variable" named `_inBlogPostList` you will instead get the result of `_blogPostListController.sink`.

The advantage of this is you get a `Sink` instance which you can call `add` and `close` on. If you don't need to `close` the sink you can instead use a `set` method to add stuff into the sink like Rémi Rousselet proposes.

Comment: Much appreciated!